# Adding Foo& to a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm writing a mock for the following interface:

```
virtual void store(const Foo& container) = 0;
```

So in the implementation I wish to save whats sent in each time in a vector, something like this:

```
virtual void store(const Foo& container)
{
    _storedContainers.push_back(container);
}
```

What type should _storedContainers have, where _storedContainers is a member of the mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store a `const` reference to `Foo` then use [`boost::cref()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/ref.html) and `boost::reference_wrapper` as plain references are not assignable and cannot be stored in a `vector`:

```
std::vector<boost::reference_wrapper<const Foo> > _storedContainers;

virtual void store(const Foo& container)
{
    _storedContainers.push_back(boost::cref(container));
}
```

However, the elements in `_storedContainers` have a potential to become dangling references if the objects passed to `store()` are destructed while still required. Online demo at http://codepad.org/VOokOm6i.

<strike>Example (using equivalent c++11 versions of `cref()` and `reference_wrapper`) http://ideone.com/0vVv8w .</strike>

Answer (score 2):

The expression `container` has type `const Foo`, so you're trying to push a `Foo` object into `_storedContainers`. That means `_storedContainers` should probably be a container of `Foo`s, such as `std::vector<Foo>`.